# I do not understand how the trigger works in this case. How the last order id equal 3, 2, 1

Tags: sql, sqlite

---

```
> CREATE TABLE widgetCustomer ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,
> last_order_id INT ); CREATE TABLE widgetSale ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
> item_id INT, customer_id INT, quan INT, price INT );
> 
> INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name) VALUES ('Bob'); INSERT INTO
> widgetCustomer (name) VALUES ('Sally'); INSERT INTO widgetCustomer
> (name) VALUES ('Fred');
> 
> SELECT * FROM widgetCustomer;
> 
> CREATE TRIGGER newWidgetSale AFTER INSERT ON widgetSale
>     BEGIN
>         UPDATE widgetCustomer SET last_order_id = NEW.id WHERE widgetCustomer.id = NEW.customer_id;
>     END ;
> 
> INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan, price) VALUES (1,
> 3, 5, 1995); INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, customer_id, quan,
> price) VALUES (2, 2, 3, 1495); INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id,
> customer_id, quan, price) VALUES (3, 1, 1, 2995); SELECT * FROM
> widgetSale; SELECT * FROM widgetCustomer;
```

---

The output is 3,2,1 in the last order ID column, but when I change the values to 2,3,1 the output will be 3,1,2. I don't understand why? What does NEW do as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM widgetCustomer
```

has no `ORDER BY`.  So, the results are in an *arbitrary* order.  If you want the results in a particular order, you need an `ORDER BY` clause.

Remember:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless you explicitly provide one.

Comment: I know that but I dont understand how this statements works "UPDATE widgetCustomer SET last_order_id = NEW.id WHERE widgetCustomer.id = NEW.customer_id;

Comment: @Jan have you read [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)?